# Thymeleaf with Ajax not working properly

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to use Thymeleaf fragments with Ajax on my project and I have this method on my controller:

```
public def displayInfo(Model model) {
    log.info("Guests method!")
    model.addAttribute("content", "testing ajax");
    "fragments/content::form-basic";
}
```

And I get this message before running the application:

```
WARNING: The [displayInfo] action in [ca.capilanou.hrpay.workload.NonInstructionalWorkloadController] accepts a parameter of type [org.springframework.ui.Model].  Interface types and abstract class types are not supported as command objects.  This parameter will be ignored.

    public def displayInfo(Model model) {
    ^
```

On the html where I want to add the fragment by ajax I have this just for testing:

```
<button id="bt1" onclick="$('#content').load('/nonInstructionalWorkload/displayInfo');">Load Frag 1</button>
<div id="content"></div>
```

What is happening is that I get the "Guests method!" message on the console, which means that it's reaching the controller, but when it tries to do:

```
model.addAttribute("content", "testing ajax");
```

I get a nullPointerException because the model parameter is coming null.
So I tried to comment this line and just return the fragment I want to display.
This is the fragment I have:

```
<th:block th:fragment="content" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <div th:text="${content}"></div>
</th:block>
```

I tried to put the ${content} text hard coded when commenting the model.addAttribute line, but I'm not getting anything back on my screen.

What do I need to do to fix the "WARNING" I'm getting and also the to be able to see the fragment being shown on the right place?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it this way:

Instead of using this method:

```
public def displayInfo(Model model) {
    log.info("Guests method!")
    model.addAttribute("content", "testing ajax");
    "fragments/content::form-basic";
}
```

I'm now using this:

```
ModelAndView addWorkItem() {
        log.info("Display Fragment using Ajax")
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/fragments/content :: content")
        modelAndView.addObject("content", "Hello World!")
        return modelAndView
    }
```

We need to return the ModelAndView. If there anything you need to use on the screen you can addObject adding its attributes.

By doing this I avoid the Model, so I get rid of the Warning issue.

That's it. I wasn't able to find this solution anywhere.. I found pieces in different articles.

https://github.com/dandelion/dandelion/issues/28

http://www.marcelustrojahn.com/2016/08/spring-boot-thymeleaf-fragments-via-ajax/

http://www.xpadro.com/2014/02/thymeleaf-integration-with-spring-part-2.html